# Grouped table of means by variable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to take a user inputed CSV with the `fileInput` and output a grouped table by a user selected item i.e. x axis and y axis contain drop down menus then output a grouped table from x axis and show grouped means for y axis. Right now when I run my code it will group the x axis but under the mean column it displays the mean of all the values.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

data1 <- reactive({
req(input$file1)
inFile <- input$file1
df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
               quote = input$quote)

updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Axis',
                  choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Axis',
                  choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
return(df)
  })
output$tabset1Selected <- renderTable({
mean.table<-group_by(data1(), as.factor(data1()[,input$xcol])) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(data1()[,input$ycol], na.rm = TRUE),
    se = std.error(data1()[,input$ycol], na.rm = TRUE))
  })
```

I am also having trouble running an `HSD.test` as well

```
res.anova <- aov(data1()[,input$ycol]~data1()[,input$xcol], data=dataset)     
HSDtest.measurement <- HSD.test(res.anova,"treatment", group = TRUE)
```

The res.anova function works but when I try and run the `HSD.test` I am unsure what to place in the "treatment" section to get it run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the code in the `group_by` to `group_by_at` as it would be a string input, then change the `input$ycol` to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) for extracting the value

```
output$tabset1Selected <- renderTable({
      data1() %>%
            group_by_at(vars(input$xcol)) %>%
            summarise(
                count = n(),
                mean = mean(!! rlang::sym(input$ycol), na.rm = TRUE),
                se = std.error(!! rlang::sym(input$ycol), na.rm = TRUE))
           })
```

---

It displays the mean of all the values because we are extracting the whole column.  For e.g

```
iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        summarise(Mean = mean(iris$Sepal.Length)) # breaks the grouping info
```

Instead, we just need the column name

```
iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

As we get a string column name as input, it. is converted to `sym`bol and evaluted (`!!`)

```
iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        summarise(Mean = mean(!! rlang::sym("Sepal.Length")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also if I was to run an `HSD.test(y, txt ...)` how can I use the `xcol` input for the `trt` portion? I keep running into errors since it normally has quotations around it.

Comment: @Seezium. Can you please update that part in your post.  It can be similar `!! rlang::sym(input$xcol)`

Comment: I updated it. I am confused since the formatting wants quotes and this is a reactive element.

Comment: @Seezium. it i a formula, so you can use `paste` to create the formula.  Instead of  `aov(data1()[,input$ycol]~data1()[,input$xcol], data=dataset)`  would be `aov(as.formula(paste0(input$ycol, " ~ ", input$xcol)), data = dataset)`  Not clear about whether the `data = dataset` or `data = data1()`

Comment: The aov formula works but I’m having problems with the HSD.test since the treatment section is in quotes if I put something like “input$xcol” it returns NULL

Comment: @Seezium. what is the package for `HSD.test`

Comment: `agricolae` `HSD.test(y, trt, DFerror, MSerror, alpha = 0.05, group=TRUE, main = NULL, 
unbalanced=FALSE,console=FALSE)`

Comment: @Seezium. In this case, you want thee unquoted one as you are passing an identifier `HSD.test(res.anova,input$xcol, group = TRUE)`.  Check the example here `data(sweetpotato);model<-aov(yield~virus, data=sweetpotato);nm1 <- "virus";out <- HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE, console = TRUE);out2 <- HSD.test(model,nm1, group=TRUE, console = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having issues with transforming the input in to a form that you can use in the dplyr group_by and summarise calls.  You can try something like this:

```
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderTable({
        data1() %>%
            group_by(!! rlang::sym(input$xcol)) %>%
            summarise(count = n(),
                      mean = mean(!! rlang::sym(input$ycol)))
    })
```

If you want your output column to be called something more descriptive you can do this:

```
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderTable({
        col_name <- paste0("mean_", input$ycol)
        data1() %>%
            group_by(!! rlang::sym(input$xcol)) %>%
            summarise(count = n(),
                      !!col_name := mean(!! rlang::sym(input$ycol)))
    })
```